# While working on image segmentation problem I am receiving error while I am trying to train my model. Which loss should i use to train my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am working on an image segmentation problem in which I have 50 training images and 51 testing images. When I tried to train my model using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` I received the following error:

> Error:ValueError: Shapes (None, 256, 256, 2) and (None, 256, 256, 1) are incompatible

Here is model definition:

```
input_shape=(256,256,3)
model = build_model(input_shape)
model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr),
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
        ]
    )
```

When I tried to use Binary cross entropy I got the following error

```
model = build_model((H, W, 3))
metrics = [dice_coef, iou, Recall(), Precision()]
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr), metrics=metrics)
```

where `H , W = 256, 256`

Model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import *

def squeeze_excite_block(inputs, ratio=8):
    init = inputs
    channel_axis = -1
    filters = init.shape[channel_axis]
    se_shape = (1, 1, filters)

    se = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(init)
    se = Reshape(se_shape)(se)
    se = Dense(filters // ratio, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)
    se = Dense(filters, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)

    x = Multiply()([init, se])
    return x

def conv_block(inputs, filters):
    x = inputs

    x = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = squeeze_excite_block(x)

    return x

def encoder1(inputs):
    skip_connections = []

    model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=inputs)
    names = ["block1_conv2", "block2_conv2", "block3_conv4", "block4_conv4"]
    for name in names:
        skip_connections.append(model.get_layer(name).output)

    output = model.get_layer("block5_conv4").output
    return output, skip_connections

def decoder1(inputs, skip_connections):
    num_filters = [256, 128, 64, 32]
    skip_connections.reverse()
    x = inputs

    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skip_connections[i]])
        x = conv_block(x, f)

    return x

# def encoder2(inputs):
#     skip_connections = []
#
#     output = DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')(inputs)
#     model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, output)
#
#     names = ["input_2", "conv1/relu", "pool2_conv", "pool3_conv"]
#     for name in names:
#         skip_connections.append(model.get_layer(name).output)
#     output = model.get_layer("pool4_conv").output
#
#     return output, skip_connections

def encoder2(inputs):
    num_filters = [32, 64, 128, 256]
    skip_connections = []
    x = inputs

    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = conv_block(x, f)
        skip_connections.append(x)
        x = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)

    return x, skip_connections

def decoder2(inputs, skip_1, skip_2):
    num_filters = [256, 128, 64, 32]
    skip_2.reverse()
    x = inputs

    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skip_1[i], skip_2[i]])
        x = conv_block(x, f)

    return x

def output_block(inputs):
    x = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding="same")(inputs)
    x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    return x

def Upsample(tensor, size):
    """Bilinear upsampling"""
    def _upsample(x, size):
        return tf.image.resize(images=x, size=size)
    return Lambda(lambda x: _upsample(x, size), output_shape=size)(tensor)

def ASPP(x, filter):
    shape = x.shape

    y1 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(shape[1], shape[2]))(x)
    y1 = Conv2D(filter, 1, padding="same")(y1)
    y1 = BatchNormalization()(y1)
    y1 = Activation("relu")(y1)
    y1 = UpSampling2D((shape[1], shape[2]), interpolation='bilinear')(y1)

    y2 = Conv2D(filter, 1, dilation_rate=1, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y2 = BatchNormalization()(y2)
    y2 = Activation("relu")(y2)

    y3 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=6, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y3 = BatchNormalization()(y3)
    y3 = Activation("relu")(y3)

    y4 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=12, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y4 = BatchNormalization()(y4)
    y4 = Activation("relu")(y4)

    y5 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=18, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y5 = BatchNormalization()(y5)
    y5 = Activation("relu")(y5)

    y = Concatenate()([y1, y2, y3, y4, y5])

    y = Conv2D(filter, 1, dilation_rate=1, padding="same", use_bias=False)(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Activation("relu")(y)

    return y

def build_model(shape):
    inputs = Input(shape)
    x, skip_1 = encoder1(inputs)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder1(x, skip_1)
    outputs1 = output_block(x)

    x = inputs * outputs1

    x, skip_2 = encoder2(x)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder2(x, skip_1, skip_2)
    outputs2 = output_block(x)
    outputs = Concatenate()([outputs1, outputs2])

    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = build_model((256, 256, 3))
    model.summary()
```

I don't know what this error is referring to and at what point. If anyone wants any further information regarding this project which can help in solving the problem I am facing, please add a comment and I will be happy to share
Thank You for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the output of your model and the error is throw when you build or when you compile the model?

Comment: Add your model architecture. At leas `model.summary()`.

Comment: I am adding the model(code) file for your reference. I am not facing any error while using model summary function